# mcrypt_decrypt sometimes doesn't decrypts fully

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have 2 servers: NAS and outer one (let's call him mail server). NAS should generate information for employees and customers, crypt message, then send to mail server where message should be decrypted and send by PHP mail() function. My problem is that the same message is every time differentially decrypted:

Original: **This is very important data**

Decrypted:

1. This is very impŇwSĚóűwË$u!'6
2. hÁMJaÎ,ÁÔăV˘ortant data
3. s|ĚĚ'ˇSR0B%0GĆŻ~ŘĽŁä&2ú
4. sometimes it's proper 'This is very important data'

How to fix it?

my code:

part of user file:

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open('twofish', '', 'cbc', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td));
$key = substr(md5('mylittlepony').sha1('flutershyismylove'), 0, 31);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, 'This is very important data');
echo message('my@mail.com', 'test', base64_encode($encrypted).'||'.base64_encode($iv));
```

File on mail server:

```
$a = explode('||', $_POST[message]);
$message = base64_decode($a[0]);
$td = mcrypt_module_open('twofish', '', 'cbc', '');
$iv = base64_decode($a[1]);
$key = substr(md5('mylittlepony').sha1('flutershyismylove'), 0, 31);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $message);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
$decrypted = trim($decrypted);
mail($to, $_POST[subject], $decrypted, $_POST[headers]);
```

message() is function which sends info by cURL to mail server.

Comment: I'm going to ask an obvious off-topic question here. Why don't you just use some functions provided by default in PHP, such as [`openssl_pkcs7_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-encrypt.php)

Comment: First, because I didn't know it, second it doesn't solve my problem (NAS have limited connections to web and can't send mails itself).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. https://3v4l.org/kihc4

Could it be because you're not `urlencode()`ing the value in your POST parameters and it's corrupting the IV and/or ciphertext?

I also notice that you're not [authenticating your ciphertext](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly). Have you considered using [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead of rolling your own cryptography? (I professionally recommend it.)

> `$key = substr(md5('mylittlepony').sha1('flutershyismylove'), 0, 31);`

I think [`hash_pbkdf2()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_pbkdf2) would be more useful here?

Comment: Problem is in IV. Sometimes it isn't even generated in first script. I've changed trim() for rtrim($decrypted, "\0") and I've added urlencode/decode. sometimes IV's are the same but message is still undecoded like :
ďÔnĚVşŕÍŁrK
ďÔnĚVşŕÍŁrK

hash_pbkdf2() is one way function unfortunately ;(
Authentication will be done when messages will work properly.

Comment: I reckon wrapping this in `urlencode()` on encryption and passing it through `urldecode()` before decrypting will help remedy this.

Comment: `hash_pbkdf2() is one way function unfortunately ;( ` Yes, that's precisely what you need of a key derivation function.

Comment: Sorry, I thought You are convincing me to use pbkdf2() instead of mcrypt(). BTW: I've spotted that my $key in second script has sometimes one char less.

Comment: Oh. No, I'd rather encourage you to use Defuse Security's PHP encryption library instead of writing your own, [unless you're writing cryptography as an educational exercise](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).

Comment: but I'm not writing my own hashing function, I wouldn't even think about it now. $key can be any string in my case. I just used this md5 + sha1 without special purpose. I just wanted to have long string and cut a part from it.

Comment: "but I'm not writing my own hashing function" Writing a high level protocol is almost as dangerous as writing a primitive. If you want secure encryption, use the Defuse library. If you want to derive a key from a password, use `hash_pbkdf2()` instead of md5 or sha1. These statements are made with the premise that security is your goal.